# Using Javascript Closures in minification

Tags: javascript, compression, closures, minify

**Here's My Javascript:**

```
document.getElementById('post').style.color = "black";
document.documentElement.className = "active";
alert(document.documentElement.clientWidth);
```

Which of the following minified versions would you say is better? Why? They're basically the same length but the second method uses an anonymous function to rename some variables.

Would there be a difference in speed (however many nanoseconds that would be)?

**Normal minification:**

```
document.getElementById('post').style.color="#000";document.documentElement.className="active";alert(document.documentElement.clientWidth);
```

**or with an anonymous function...**

```
(function(){var d=document,h=d.documentElement;d.getElementById('post').style.color="#000";h.className="active";alert(h.clientWidth)})();
```

Comment: Whichever one gzips to the smallest number of bytes? ;-) I wouldn't worry about any performance differences, they're bound to be minute.

Comment: Check gzipped sizes.  Aliasing of variables (i.e. your var d = document etc.) may increase gzipped sizes because variable names are automatically compressed by gzipped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second one `(function(){var d=document,h=d.documentElement;d.getElementById('post').style.color="#000";h.className="active";alert(h.clientWidth)})();` is better because it has in its local scope the global variables' local copy and it is faster. This has performance advantages in garbage collection and scope chain walking.
[Ref](http://briancray.com/2012/02/23/javascript-module-pattern/) (localized section)

Comment: Are you sure? ...There are no user defined variables in my snippet. I thought that just the **user defined** global variables were slow. Maybe I'm wrong?

Comment: Read that article. Thanks for the link!